# If $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle, what does it mean that $E^X$ is equal to $M$ such that $E^X \subset E$?

Tags: vector-bundles

I've come across this statement:

> Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a G-equivariant vector bundle. Suppose that there exists $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $E^X =M$: the vector field on $E$ induced by $X$ vanishes exactly on $M$.

My question is :

what does it mean that $E^X$ which is a subset of  $E$ is equal to $M$ which might be different from $E$ ?

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question: $M$ in the statement is identified with $i(M)$, which is the image of $M$ under the zero section map  $i: M \rightarrow E .$